# Why the IndexOf(String str, int fromIndex) is not available when I try to find it in str

Tags: java

When I am trying to find    indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) in my java project I am not getting it in String functions available. Is it because of the project setting?

Comment: Post the whole code please.

Comment: public class String_functions {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String str = "Learning Java for project";
  
  System.out.println(str.charAt(13));
  System.out.println(str.length());
  System.out.println(str.indexOf('e'));
  System.out.println(str.

Comment: Now when I type str. the indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) function is not available

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a problem of IDE itself. You may restart it and try again. Even if there are no combobox /a list of methods it does not mean you can not use those methods.

Comment: Thanks M Ciel but I am getting this message when I move my mouse over the function (int java.lang.String.indexOf(String arg0, int arg1)


Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.)